# Update/refresh livewire blade using intermediate updates from component method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire 3 component with a method that takes a while and I would like to the page to show the latest status.

I'm relatively new to this, so I may not understand binding / refresh well enough.
What I tried was:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TestUpdate extends Component
{
    public $status;

    public function mount() {
        $this->status = 'zero';
    }

    public function update() {
        $this->status = 'one';

        $this->dispatch('$refresh');

        sleep(3);

        $this->status = 'two';
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-update');
    }
}
```

and as Blade:

```
<div>

    <form wire:submit="update">
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>

    {{-- option 1 --}}
    <div>
        {{ $status }}
    </div>

    {{-- option 2 --}}
    <input type="text" wire:model="status" placeholder="nothing...">

</div>
```

But this shows `zero` before and during the action, and `two` afterwards.
What can be done so `one` is shown as well?

Comment: Questions like yours are common lately. The backend side of the process is not multitasking and the result is that all actions performed during processing are sent together at the end. Furthermore I don't think *$refresh* can be sent from the backend, it is usually requested from the frontend

Comment: That makes sense. Would a `wire:poll` or websocket be the recommended approach then?
For $refresh, I saw this was suggested, but it's not working in the example above. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-v3-how-to-run-refresh-or-refresh-component-from-inside-method?page=1&replyId=915431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Livewire is busy, it will not update the frontend. The dispatch happens *after* the method is finished. If you want to perform a long running task while keeping track of its status, it's suggested to queue a job and keep its progress in the database. This way you can use `wire:poll` to read the database and update the frontend.

Other options are generally more hacky, such as having a JavaScript callback to trigger the update if status == 1.